# How to split a mesh methodically based on tris count

Tags: mesh

I have a very big mesh and the tris count is very high, even with the decimate tool making it look horrible it is still too much to upload to my game engine, is there a plugin or a way to seperate it into smaller meshes based on a tris limit (like 10k) and then import them altogether?[image]

Comment: Depending on what your mesh is, you may have vertex normal issues when splitting it (just a comment). You should also indicate some picture about how the mesh looks like (if it is a terrain, for instance, the solution could be different).

Comment: I added a picture, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: OK, here, why don't you simply separate by loose parts? and chunks may be some amount of parts.

Comment: that's what i'm saying but I can't do it by hand